# CSS not showing proper

Tags: html, css, magento

[Issue in CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5gOO.png)

i have attached the image of the issue ,i have included header on all the pages .
case 1 : i m on home page , and toggles this switch (its CSS remains same )
case 2 : if i go to any other page from the links on header , the css for this select changes like showing in 2nd .
so on toggle it changes .

I m using magento , and the file is **style.css** ,also its alignment is not proper if the select is opened it takes whole width of the header ,which i have changed to 20% for now.

```css
#footer .store-switcher,
#footer .form-language,
#footer .form-currency {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;  }
#footer .store-switcher label,
#footer .form-language label,
#footer .form-currency label {display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; font-size: .91em; color: #aaa; margin-right: 6px;}
#footer .store-switcher .sbHolder,
#footer .form-language .sbHolder,
#footer .form-currency .sbHolder {display: inline-block; }
```

```css
select {height: 30px;margin-right:30px; color: #666; background-color: #eee; border-color: #666;}
select option { padding-right:10px; }
select.multiselect{height:auto;}
select.multiselect option { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; padding:2px 5px; }
select.multiselect option:last-child { border-bottom:0; }
```

```css
/*
 styles for select
*/
.sbHolder{
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: normal;
 position: relative;
 width: auto;
}
.sbSelector{
 display: block;
 height:auto;
 margin-left: 30px;
    width:15%;
 left: 0;
 outline: none;
 overflow: hidden;
 text-indent:0;
 top: 0; 
    margin-top:0;
 color:#8a8a8a;
    border:solid 1px #eee;
    padding:4px 12px 5px;
    background:#fff;
}
.sbSelector:hover {-moz-transition:all 300ms ease;-webkit-transition:all 300ms ease;-o-transition:all 300ms ease;transition:all 300ms ease;border-color:#eee;background-color:#eee;color:#aaa;}
.sbSelector:hover > span {border-top-color:#aaa;}
.sbSelector span.text {
    float:left;
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    background:none;
    margin:0;
    border:none;
}
.sbSelector.price {font-size:1em!important;}
.sbSelector > span {
    display:block;
    float:right;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    margin:7px 0px 7px 5px;
    border-left: 4px solid transparent;
    border-right: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid #aaa;
}
.sbSelector > span span{
    display:block;
    height:12px;
}
.sbSelector:link, .sbSelector:visited, .sbSelector:hover{ 
 outline: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.sbToggle{
 display: none;
 height: 20px;
 outline: none;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 width: 30px;
}
.sbToggle:hover {}
.sbToggleOpen {}
.sbToggleOpen:hover {}
.sbHolderDisabled {background-color: #3C3C3C; border: solid 1px #515151;}
.sbHolderDisabled .sbHolder {}
.sbHolderDisabled .sbToggle {}
.sbOptions{
 list-style: none;
 left: 257px;
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
    top:30px!important;
 position:absolute;
    max-height:150px!important;
    border:none;
 z-index: 999;
 overflow-y: auto;
 background:#eee;
    
}
.sbOptions li a, .toolbar .sbOptions li a {line-height:2.8em;padding:0 15px;font-family:Arial;}
.sbOptions li:hover {background-color:#ddd}
.sbOptions li:first-child a{border-top:none;}
.sbOptions a {
 display: block;
 outline: none;
 padding:3px 20px 3px 0;
    -moz-transition:none;
    -webkit-transition:none;
    -o-transition:0;
    transition:none;
 color:#888;
    font-size:11px;
}
.sbOptions a:link,
.sbOptions a:visited{color: #888; text-decoration: none;}
.sbOptions a:hover{color:#888;}
.sbOptions li.last a{border-bottom: none;}
.sbOptions .sbDisabled{
 border-bottom: solid 1px #515151;
 color: #999;
 display: block;
 padding: 7px 0 7px 3px;
}
.sbOptions .sbGroup{
 border-bottom: solid 1px #515151;
 color: #EBB52D;
 display: block;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 7px 0 7px 3px;
}
.sbOptions .sbSub{padding-left: 17px;}
.sbHolder .sbToggleOpen + .sbSelector {
     border-color:#eee;
     background-color:#eee;
     color:#aaa;
}
.sbHolder .sbToggleOpen + .sbSelector > span.text {background:none;}
.sbHolder .sbToggleOpen + .sbSelector > span {border-top-color:#aaa;}
```